# Apache2 server and Superset, 502 Proxy Error, error reading from remote server while dashboards loading

Tags: amazon-ec2, proxy, apache2, apache-superset, dremio

### Short introduction

I have Apache Superset and Apache2 server located on the same EC2 instance. Apache2 is acting as a proxy server. It accepts HTTPS requests and transfers them to Apache Superset. Apache Superset is run using `gunicorn`.

### Problem

Requests to Apache Dremio data engine could take some time (< 60 seconds). When accessing dashboards on Superset, using DNS name with SSL, with proxy setup some dashboards parts (requests) are failing with the following error:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request
Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Strangely, these errors can appear in a matter of seconds despite that default value for `ProxyTimeout` is quite high.

The problem doesn't occur if Superset is accessed by IP address.

Error message in `apache2/error.log`:

```
(20014) Internal error (specific information not available): [client 10.4.26.3:6969] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8088, referer: ...
```

### What was tried to solve a problem

Problem can be with proxy server timeout or with Superset web server dropping some connections. My Apache2 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName dash.domain.com
  ServerAlias dash.domain.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/cert.crt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/cert2.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/key.key

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8088/ connectiontimeout=3600 timeout=3600
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8088/

  # things tried
  # SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
  # SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
  # SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
  # ProxyTimeout 3600
  # TimeOut 3600
</VirtualHost>
```

Things tested (and not working):

1. `Timeout` and `ProxyTimeout`
2. `connectiontimeout` and `timeout` (as seen above)
3. `Keepalive=On` for ProxyPass
4. different SetEnv
5. `superset_config.py` -> ENABLE_PROXY_FIX, SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT

In addition, similar proxy setup was build using `nginx`, error is similar to what is described here.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

#### Useful information

Apache Superset version: *0.37.2*

Apache Dremio version: *4.1.0*

Apache2 server version: *2.4.29*

EC2 instance type: *t3.medium*

OS version: *Ubuntu 18.04*

Comment: What is your DNS setup?

Comment: DNS is working fine. I don't know what do you mean by "DNS setup".

Comment: "The problem doesn't occur if Superset is accessed by IP address." Given that the same problem occurs with Nginx, the DNS might *not* be working fine.

Comment: But I still can access dashboards and they are partially working. When accessing by IP address, I am not using Apache Proxy but directly Superset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in dying gunicorn **async** workers. Too many requests were coming from the charts and workers were not able to handle them. Changing worker type from async to **sync** (default gunicorn type) solved the proxy problem.

I still don't know why direct access by IP was not producing the 502 proxy error.

Sorry for not including information about `gunicorn` in the question.

P.S Recommended type of workers for Apache Superset from their docs is **async**, but, for my case, **sync** were the better solution. In theory, sync workers are slower compare to async (in Superset context).

Answer (score 1):

Following this detailed article: https://www.tessian.com/blog/how-to-fix-http-502-errors/

We have tried the suggested fix (based on AWS ALB default connection idle timeout = 60s setting ):

```
Gunicorn (Python)
As command line arguments:

--keep-alive 65
```

Works like a charm!

And to explain "why direct access by IP was not producing the 502 proxy error", check this Gunicorn settings doc:
https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#keepalive

```
Generally set in the 1-5 seconds range for servers with direct connection to the client (e.g. when you don’t have separate load balancer).
```

Since the default keepalive setting is 2 seconds, it works well on direct access by IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advice I've struggled for a while to resolve it!